# If else statement append to list in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, turtle-graphics

I want to add the turtle 'person' to the list 'infected_people' but I get the error 'TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: red'.

How do I add the 'person' to the list 'infected_people' without getting an error.

I am new to programming so sorry if my explanation isn't clear.

```
infected_people = []

i = 0
while i < 30: #number of steps (time)
  for person in people: 
      random_walk(30, 400)
      i + 1
      for infected_person in infected_people: 
          if person.distance(infected_person) < 30: 
              person.color("red")
              infected_people.append(person)
```

Here is the other part of my code:

```
import turtle
import random

wn = turtle.Screen()

def person_characteristics(): 
    for person in people:
        person.penup()
        person.shape("circle")
        person.shapesize(0.2)
        x = random.randint(-200, 200)
        y = random.randint(-200, 200)
        person.setpos(x, y)
        person.speed(0)
        turtle.update()
    return person


def population(population_size):
    turtle.update()
    people = []
    for _ in range(population_size):
        people.append(turtle.Turtle())
    return people

def person_characteristics(): 
    for person in people:
        turtle.update()
        person.penup()
        person.shape("circle")
        person.shapesize(0.2)
        person.speed(0)
        x = random.randint(-200, 200)
        y = random.randint(-200, 200)
        person.setpos(x, y)
    return person

def random_walk(step_size, area_size):
    person.clear()
    count = 0
    while count < 1:
        count += 1
        if (-area_size < person.xcor() <area_size) and (-area_size < person.ycor() <area_size):
            person.right(random.randint(0,360))
            person.forward(step_size)
        else:
            person.right(180)
            person.forward(step_size)
    turtle.update()

people = population(50)
person = person_characteristics()

def infect_random(people):
    infected = random.choice(people)
    infected.color("red")
    return infected

infected_people = []
initial_infected = infect_random(people)
infected_people.append(initial_infected)
print(infected_people)
counted_infections = 0
```

My goal is that every infected_person (= red dot) infects every other person which comes close to him. Now only the initial infected person infects other people. So I thought if I add every person who gets infected to the list of infected_people, then it would work. However I get an error when the line  infected_people.append(person) is added.

```
i = 0
while i < 30: #number of steps (time)
    for person in people: 
        random_walk(30, 400)
        i += 1
        for infected_person in infected_people: 
            if person.distance(infected_person) < 30: 
                person.color("red")
                infected_people.append(person)



turtle.done()
wn.exitonclick()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Noa Hoogeweg/Documents/BMT/PvL/Virus/Noa_Virus_goed.py', wdir='C:/Users/Noa Hoogeweg/Documents/BMT/PvL/Virus')
[<turtle.Turtle object at 0x000001FF4D3D9908>]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Noa Hoogeweg\Documents\BMT\PvL\Virus\Noa_Virus_goed.py", line 78, in <module>
    person.color("red")

  File "C:\Users\Noa Hoogeweg\anaconda3\lib\turtle.py", line 2216, in color
    pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)

  File "C:\Users\Noa Hoogeweg\anaconda3\lib\turtle.py", line 2696, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)

  File "C:\Users\Noa Hoogeweg\anaconda3\lib\turtle.py", line 1158, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color string: %s" % str(color))

TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: red
```

Comment: Could you please add the input and error you are receiving to your question?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you instead pass rgb values as ` color(r,g,b)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `person.color("red")` looks perfectly valid, and I don't get the error when I run the code.

Working from your error's stacktrace, turtle only does two things with your color string.  First, it tests if it's a `str` -- yours had to pass that test to get the error you got.  Second, it passes the color string onto tkinter's `winfo_rgb()` method which returns an RGB triple.  Turtle ignores the triple, it just wants to see if that function succeeds or throws an error.  If it throws an error, you get the message you showed:

```
TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: red
```

So the ball's in tkinter's court, give the following little program a try to see if tkinter is doing the right thing by you:

```
from tkinter import Button

# Button is an arbitrary widget choice
print(Button().winfo_rgb("red"))
```

If it works, you should get something like:

```
> python3 test.py
(65535, 0, 0)
>
```

In which case, there's something suspicious going on with your turtle code in the way that it hooks up with the tkinter library.  If the above fails, you should get something like:

```
> python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(Button().winfo_rgb("red"))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1156, in winfo_rgb
    self.tk.call('winfo', 'rgb', self._w, color))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "red"
>
```

In which case you may need to look into the validity of your tkinter installation.

Even if you fix the `"red"` problem, there are other errors in your code that will keep it from working.  Below is my rewrite to get it to run properly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

def person_characteristics(people):
    for person in people:
        person.shape('circle')
        person.shapesize(0.2)
        person.speed('fastest')
        person.penup()
        x = randint(-200, 200)
        y = randint(-200, 200)
        person.setpos(x, y)
        person.showturtle()

def population(population_size):
    people = []

    for _ in range(population_size):
        people.append(Turtle(visible=False))

    return people

def random_walk(person, step_size, area_size):
    if -area_size < person.xcor() < area_size and -area_size < person.ycor() < area_size:
        person.right(randint(0, 360))
        person.forward(step_size)
    else:
        person.right(180)
        person.forward(step_size)

def infect_random(people):
    infected = choice(people)
    infected.color('red')
    return infected

screen = Screen()

people = population(50)
person_characteristics(people)

infected_people = []
initial_infected = infect_random(people)
infected_people.append(initial_infected)

counted_infections = 1

for _ in range(3000): # number of steps (time)
    for person in people:
        random_walk(person, 30, 400)

        for infected_person in infected_people:
            if person.pencolor() != 'red' and person.distance(infected_person) < 30:
                person.color('red')
                infected_people.append(person)
                break

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what error you are getting, but the `i + 1` line will not increment i, to increase the value of i you need to use `i = i + 1` or `i += 1`.